# Read files and put content in an Array

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to simply read the whole content of a file and put it in an Array (elements would be lines so array[2] would get the third line, etc).

I tried:

```
originalFileContentArray = new string[] { fileReader.ReadToEnd() };
```

Which I believe is a good idea since everything I found about this was big loops to read the file line by line and push it into an array...

The problem with my idea is that the lines does not get separated automatically so the array contains only ONE big element with the whole content in it.

Any idea about how to correctly separate the content into multiple elements?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`File.ReadAllLines()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx) instead:

```
originalFileContentArray = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `String.Split` or `File.ReadAllLines()`

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to have all of the lines in memory so that you can manipulate them, then [File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx) is the way to go. But if you just need to process the file line-by-line, then use [File.ReadLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx):

```
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(filename))
{
    // process this line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
originalFileContentArray = fileReader.ReadToEnd().Split(new char[] {'\r'});
```

Comment: That would give lines that have `\n` as the first character, except for the first line. And the last line of the file would just contain a single `\n` character. You could potentially do this by splitting on `\r\n`, but using `File.ReadAllLines` is a cleaner solution.

Answer (score -1):

I would create an array from a text file like so (each line is an element):

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\users\" + Environment.UserName + @"\desktop\data.txt");
```

And then roll through it like so:

```
foreach (string line in lines) { // manipulate data here  }
```

Let me know if this helps

Comment: Compared to @BrokenGlass's answer, all you have added is an example of a very bad way to make a file path.